# Can blob storage be shared between different regions?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-regions

I want to implement a multi-region architecture in azure. My current architecture is running in one region and I am using blob storage to save my data. I was wondering if the blob storage can be shared between users in different regions? because I have seen that the replication is read-only otherwise I have to create another blob storage for the other regions ? and how I synchronize it to have the same data so the users in different regions can see the same content in the software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if the blob storage can be shared between users in
> different regions?

Blob storage can certainly be shared between users in different regions. Blob storage resources are accessible over HTTP protocol so it doesn't really matter where your users are.

However please note that you may incur extra charges for data egress if the blob storage data is consumed by the application in your secondary regions.

Furthermore, you will notice some increased latency for both reads and writes. You can reduce the read latency by fronting your blob storage with CDN (but then you will pay extra for the CDN).

Comment: So in my case storage replication cannot be applied right? because only the primary region will be able to write/ read data in the storage?